# select any tr and/or td and hide an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to find an answer here but can't get this done!

I have a table with a few rows. Some have a name in a cell others an upload id. Like so:

```
<tr>
 <td>blabla</td>
 <td>Name: Messi</td>
 <td><a id="upload-button" href=".."/>button</a></td>
 <td>blabla</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>blabla</td>
 <td>upload id: 123456</td>
 <td><a id="upload-button" href=".."/>button</a></td>
 <td>blabla</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>blabla</td>
 <td>upload id: 654321</td>
 <td><a id="upload-button" href=".."/>button</a></td>
 <td>blabla</td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to find every td with `name` in it. Just the word `name` and not `name: messi`. 
If that word is present then hide the `#upload-button` in the next td. I really can't figure that one out.

What I have is this and both don't work. Can anybody help me with this??

```
$('tr:has(td:contains("name"))').closest('#upload-button').hide(); //doesnt work


    $("tr td:contains('name')").each(function(){
      $(this).siblings('td').css("visibility","hidden");
    });//doesnt work
```

Comment: [From the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/): `jQuery( ":contains(text)" )`
*text:* A string of text to look for. It's ***case sensitive***.

Comment: Also, `closest` looks for parent elements, not descendant ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of creative filtering and finding.

```js
$(function(){

     $('tr td').filter(function(){
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('name')>-1;
      }) // first find only the td's containing the text you want
      .parent() // step up to the tr
      .find('a') // find the `a` - only because you've duplicated id's. This could be any selector
      .hide();  // hide it
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>blabla</td>
 <td>Name: Messi</td>
 <td><a id="upload-button" href=".."/>button</a></td>
 <td>blabla</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>blabla</td>
 <td>upload id: 123456</td>
 <td><a id="upload-button" href=".."/>button</a></td>
 <td>blabla</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>blabla</td>
 <td>upload id: 654321</td>
 <td><a id="upload-button" href=".."/>button</a></td>
 <td>blabla</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Be careful: id's should be unique.

Comment: thx for the answer it worked! Answer below was a bit faster :)

Comment: @Meules - Answer you accepted does something different to what you asked - it hides the entire td rather than the button.

Comment: That's why I said that their discussion lead to the correct answer. But you're right, your code does actually what I asked for...

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following:

```
$('td').each(function(){
    //check if contains 'name'
    if( this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'name' ) !== -1 ) {
        // I think next is better as siblings -> selects only the button td
        //$(this).siblings('td').css("visibility","hidden");
        $(this).next('td').css("visibility","hidden");
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
Added `.toLowerCase()` based on the comments ;-)

Comment: Be careful, `indexOf` is case sensitive!

Comment: vote up for being the only one to realise that he's looking to match on just the word 'name', and not looking for elements with just the text 'name'

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon easily solved with `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: @JamieBarker yes, i know, still, should mention it. OP doesn't seem to know that `contains` is case sensitive.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon It's a bit unhelpful to the OP if you just point out a problem, without giving an answer to said problem ;)

Comment: @JamieBarker Well, my comment wasn't for the asker, but for the answerer so he could modify his answer. I always prefer showing the problem instead of the solution (better for learning) and when I posted the comment, Jamiec already answered with the solution anyway.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Fair enough. Of course you could also edit the answer for him and skip the whole process entirely...

Comment: Thank you both :) Your discussion lead to the correct answer!

Comment: @JamieBarker Ahah indeed I could've but then, TheGr8_Nik wouldn't have learned. Not only the asker has to learn, but sometime, the answerer can learn from their mistake. I learned a lot by answering and watching other better answers. Anyway, everyone has their own method. Mine is pointing errors!